# How can I cover the unfinished edge of particle board?

Tags: furniture, self-assembly-furniture

I am new to this forum so please excuse if this is off topic. I am having trouble figuring out how to fix my entertainment center / TV stand. I recently bought it from Amazon and assembled it at home. I made a mistake while assembling and as a result, one of the unpolished edge which should be towards behind, is now in front and looks bad (please refer to the picture).

I realized this while adding the last few bits but since this is not great quality furniture, I was worried disassembling and reassembling it will make it wobbly / loose. Also, the back portion has nails put into the polished part that would come in front. So, it was already not an option.

Is there a way I can cover these unpolished edges so that it does not look bad? I was thinking of paining them but want to get suggestions. Also, where can I get options, I mean which stores (home depot?). Or if I can get that kind of surface coating / polish somewhere.

Any suggestions are welcome. Please help me fix this.

[image: TV stand image]

Comment: Unless it's glued together, I'd just take it apart and put it back together the right way -- I've got similar cheap particle board furniture that's been disassembled and reassembled after 4 moves and I haven't had any problems with it. Even if you have a couple nail holes in the finished piece, that's got to be easier to patch than an entire unfinished strip.

Comment: @Johnny, it is not glued together, just screws, if I don't find an easier way I will disassemble it then. Thanks for giving this information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd still take it apart, but I understand your reluctance.

What you need is "edge banding tape". You should be able to find it online in black. (The big box stores don't usually have a good color selection, but you might get lucky.) Anyway, once you have it, you'll want to iron it onto the edge. (A couple of layers of aluminum foil will keep your iron clean.) After ironing and while it's still warm, rub it with something like a block of wood or a wine cork to force the tape down. Let cool, cut the edges that hang over with a utility knife and you're done.

Comment: Just to add a few hints to the fix. Trimming the edges flush with a razor knife will do the job, just be sure the blade is new. A dull or used blade is a sure way to cut into places you do not want to go. Get it close and use a file to smooth it to the edge of the wood it is bonded to. use the file at an angle so it never touches the face of any wood, only the corner. 100G sandpaper will work in a pinch, but only with a block to back up the paper. After the texture is smooth with the edge banding, use a black permanent marker to color the new face. Or mask it and paint it

Comment: @Jack thank you for the tips, I am all excited to fix this now :)

Comment: YW, the hints referred to an unfinished wood iron on edge banding, this is readily available in big box stores. If you do find it in black, it would save a step or two.

Answer (score 1):

This will be easily fixed and leaves no trace at all by the use of "iron-on edging" which can be bought from most of the building/hardware stores like Bunnings (if you live in Australia). They are suitable for DIY purpose. Simply follow the instruction on the package. Tools you will need: household iron, sharp knife or brand-new old-fashioned razor blade, and some rag. Have fun and enjoy the "I fixed it" feeling.